# Ensuring the program retrieves the credentials from the database BEFORE setting them

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, spotify

I am relatively new to Javascript and promises so I am not sure how to ensure that the code follows a certain order in this scenario.

Fundamentally, I need to retrieve the credentials from the database before setting them. How do I ensure that the retrieval code happens before the setting code - is there a way to use async and await to do this?

Code that needs to be completed first starts with **`**admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get().then(async (snapshot) => {**`**

Code that needs to come second is

```
**client_id: Credentials.client_id,
        client_secret: Credentials.client_secret**
```

```js
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseio.com`
});


admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get().then(async (snapshot) => {
    await snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id));
        // Credentials.client_id = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret));
        // Credentials.client_secret = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret);
        let client_id = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id);
        let client_secret = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret);


        const regex = /(\w)+/g;

        let m;
        let n;
        while ((m = regex.exec(client_id)) !== null) {
            // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
            if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                regex.lastIndex++;
            }

            // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
            m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
                Credentials.client_id = match;
                console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);

            });
        }
        while ((n = regex.exec(client_secret)) !== null) {
            // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
            if (n.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                regex.lastIndex++;
            }

            // The result can be accessed through the `n`-variable.
            n.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
                Credentials.client_secret = match;
                console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);

            });
        }
    });


});

class Credentials {

    constructor(client_id, client_secret) {
        this.client_id = client_id;
        console.log('Id in class ' + this.client_id);
        this.client_secret = client_secret;
        console.log('Secret in class ' + this.client_secret);

    }

}

/**
 * ----------------------Below section of code found at: LINK TO GIT REPOSTITORY---------------------------------
 */
// Spotify OAuth 2 setup
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const Spotify = new SpotifyWebApi({
    
    client_id: Credentials.client_id,
    client_secret: Credentials.client_secret,
    redirectUri: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com/popup.html`
});
```

I am getting either an [object Promise] or undefined when the program runs. But on the console logs, a few seconds after it logs the data that I need. Really stuck on this one - anyone know how to solve this? (code below is its current state which leads to the [object Promise] situation.

```
client_id: Promise.resolve(admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get().then(async (snapshot) => {
        await snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id);})})),
    client_secret: (admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get().then(async (snapshot) => {
        await snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret);})})),
```

Comment: You are using `await` on a `forEach` method. `forEach` is not an asynchronous function.

Comment: I have taken away the await keyword (I believe I trialled that to see if it made any difference but as you say it makes sense that it had no effect). The issue remains however of only returning a Promise object rather than the data inside the promise sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already retrieving the the credentials first with this line

```
admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get()
```

This function returns a `Promise` which you can either continue on with `then`, as you already have, or use `async/await` to retrieve the value from the function.

## Promises & Async/Await

Use it as a `Promise` with `then`.

```
await admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get().then((snapshot => {
    // Credentials have been retrieved.
    // Continue here to use the credentials.
});
```

Or use it in a `async/await` function.

```
async function getCredentials() {
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get();
    return snapshot;
}
```

Both will return a `Promise` but the choice is up to you.

Now there are a couple of things that have to be changed in your code, either being in the wrong position or using it in a faulty manner.

## Credentials

You've created a `class` called **Credentials**. While the class definition is correct the instantiation is not. To create a new instance of a `class` use the `new` keyword. A `class` is virtually a blueprint of an object which can be created at any point in the code with the `new` keyword.

```
const client_id = 'yourclientid';
const client_secret = 'yourclientsecret';
const credentials = new Credentials(client_id, client_secret);

// {
//     client_id: 'yourclientid',
//     client_secret: 'yourclientsecret'
// }
```

## Placement

Because `admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get()` is an asynchronous function it will not stop the processing of the file. The rest of file will be executed without waiting for the retrieval of the credentials. But you want to do something with the credentials **after** they've been retrieved. You can do that with the `then` method of the `Promise`. `then` is called whenever a `Promise` has `resolved`. Meaning that it is finished waiting and can continue.

So the `Spotify` part has to be **inside** the `then` method whenever the credentials have been retrieved.

```
admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get().then((snapshot) => {
    // We are in the then method, so credentials have been retrieved.

    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
       // Check the credentials...
       // ...

       // Create your credentials object. 
       const credentials = new Credentials(client_id, client_secret);

       // Create new Spotify session.
       const Spotify = new SpotifyWebApi({
           client_id: credentials.client_id,
           client_secret: credentials.client_secret,
           redirectUri: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com/popup.html`
       });

    });
});
```

## Require

Not that it will matter a whole lot, but it is good practice to put your `require` statements on the top of the page. This makes it clear for you, or any other that reads code, what files or dependencies are included in this file.

```
// Put me at the top of the page.
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
```

## Conclusion

This is all what I can tell from looking through your code. You are on the right track but still need to read up more on how `Promises` work and more importantly **why** and **when** do you use them.

Create the `Spotify` session inside the `then` method callback and use the `new` keyword to create an instance of your `Credentials` class.